# How To Restart PC in Safe Mode and do some stuff

Tags: bash, batch, vbscript, regedit, autologon

I had some task these days to automate removing antivirus from PC-s in our company... on some PC-s there was a password mismatch issue so we had to restart PC in safe mode to remove the config files and then we were able to remove the antivirus itself... so i wrote some scripts to automate it... The logic was this:

1) run the file which will set the password and enable built in administrator account. Copy two batch files (file1, file2) on C disk for Further work, run file 1 As administrator...

2)file 1 contains instructions and reg keys to restart computer in safe mode, autologin, run the file2 instead of explorer.exe... then deletes itself...

3)file2 contains instructions to restart computer in normal mode, delete config file of antivirus, sets default values for normal startup of explorer... then deletes itself...

actually it did work: after this script is launched - computer restarts in safe mode, administrator account automatically logs on, deletes config file, restarts in normal mode and everything seems nice and clean... but in some cases i was not able to restart in safe mode... and in other case computer restarted ins safe mode administrator account automatically got log on and then nothing happened...

so what i did wrong?

here are the files with code:

Main file which was launched by administrative privileges:

```
@echo off
net user Administrator Pass12345
net user Administrator /active:yes
xcopy "Bat_F\file1.bat" "C:\" /Y
xcopy "Bat_F\file2.bat" "C:\" /Y
"Bat_F\Runas.vbs"
```

Runas file:

```
Option explicit
dim oShell
set oShell=Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run "runas /profile /user:Administrator ""C:\file1.bat"""
WScript.Sleep 100
oShell.Sendkeys "Pass12345~"
Wscript.Quit
```

file1 :

```
@echo off
bcdedit /set {default} safeboot minimal
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d Administrator /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d Pass12345 /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoLogonCount /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Shell /t REG_SZ /d "C:\file2.bat" /f
shutdown -r -t 10 -c "Computer Will Now Restart In SAFE MODE..."
del "%~f0"
```

file2 :

```
@echo off
bcdedit /deletevalue {default} safeboot
del "C:\\Programdata\SomeAntivirus\Someconfigfile.cfg"
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v Shell /t REG_SZ /d "explorer.exe" /f
shutdown -r -t 10 -c "Computer Will Now Restart In NORMAL MODE..."
del "%~f0"
```

so what do i do wrong? or what would you suggest / reccomend?? what can i do for troubleshooting???

Comment: I see a few issues - runas.vbs is executing "runas" without an extension, so could cause a loop. xcopy is copying to "c:\" with a `\"` which escapes the quote. remove those quotes. the destination, the root of the C: drive, is also usually protected so unless the initial "main" process has rights to write there it'll choke on those lines which will leave you in limbo later. you're not removing the autologin options or disabling the administrator account in file2. using sendkeys is terrifying for security, since it would insert the password into any app that had focus.

Comment: vbs might not be associated with anything, so using cscript or wscript to call it would be safer. if you're running these across the network, then the initial setup would be safer if called via psexec.

Comment: @shawn thank you for your reply and advice!!!